# Running external functions before schema.save method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

As far as I know Mongooses `schema.save()` method is Asynchronous is nature. Is it possible to run external functions before the `schema.save()` method in sequence so `schema.save()` doesn't get called until the external functions are done processing.

```
//External function 
incrementTotal(req,res);

    newSurvey.save(function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
             sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err)
        } else{
            console.log("3")
             sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data);
        }
    });
```

**The issue:**

There are certain situations where `newSurvey.save` runs before `incrementTotal` can finish processing. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your things inside the incrementTotal callback. Libraries like [Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) etc helps in these kind of problems.

```
incrementTotal(req,function(err,res){
  if(!err){
     newSurvey.save(function (err, data) {
       if(err) {
          sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err)
       } else{
         console.log("3")
         sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data);
       }
     });
  }else{
    console.log(err);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library you can make use of `waterfall`. It takes an array of functions which are executed in series, each passing their results to the next in the array. If any of the tasks pass an error to the callback, the next function is not executed, and the main callback is immediately called with the error.

```
async.waterfall([
  incrementTotal,
  mySaveFunction,
],
function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err)
  } else {
    console.log("3")
    sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data);
  }
});

function incrementTotal(callback) {
  callback(null, data);
}

function mySaveFunction(data, callback) {
  // 'data' is the result of incrementTotal
  // so this should be newSurvey.save
  callback(null, data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this out and let you know. Just one question though, should one always use either callbacks or libraries like async when dealing with situations where you need to run a sequence of events in an asynchronous environment? Im trying to get my concepts clear.

Comment: Using the async library would be recommended because it simplifies your code. Imagine you had more functions to call, using callbacks you will construct the dreaded pyramid of doom, meanwhile with `async.waterfall` you are merely adding another element to the array.